# Using np.where and contains, distribute regex substrings to corresponding columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hellow to everyone.
I am exhausted for days with my current task and i hope somebody offer a helping hand.
I have a dataframe with player's stats filled with numbers and or zeros for every stat category. The problem is with the column **"Notes"** that contains description of an action if it happens. When a player has two different actions, the cell content is unconsistent with back to back strings without spaces.
What am i try to do is:

1. Search column that contains the word e.g. **"woodwork"**
2. Extract the following number after semicolon (and only that)
3. Assign it to already existent column named accordingly.
4. Continue with the next keyword e.g **"Big chances missed"** always considering that its
   position is never fixed.

**What i have tried so far:**

```
Players_A['Woodwork'] = np.where(Players_A['Notes'].str.contains('Hit woodwork', regex= True), Players_A['Att_Notes'].str.extract(r'(?<=Hit woodwork :)(\d)'), '')
```

That code returns Nan for matched values

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2NgW.png)

Comment: Please provide your dataset as text, not image, for reproducibility

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem inside your Regex. Here's the corrected code:

```py
df["Woodwork"] = np.where(df['Notes'].str.contains('Hit woodwork', regex=False), df['Notes'].str.extract(r'(?<=Hit woodwork: )(\d+)', expand=False), '')
df["Big_Chances"] = np.where(df['Notes'].str.contains('Big chances missed', regex=False), df['Notes'].str.extract(r'(?<=Big chances missed: )(\d+)', expand=False), '')
df
```

**Output:**

| Pl_Name | Notes | Woodwork | Msd Pen | Big_Chances | Created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Leny Yoro | - |  |  |  |  |
| Tiago Santos | - |  |  |  |  |
| Adam Ounas | Hit woodwork: 1 | 1 |  |  |  |
| Alexsandro Ribeiro | - |  |  |  |  |
| Nabil Bentaleb | - |  |  |  |  |
| Edon Zhegrova | Big chances missed: 1 |  |  | 1 |  |
| Ismaily | - |  |  |  |  |
| Rémy Cabella | Hit woodwork: 1Big chances missed: 1 | 1 |  | 1 |  |
| Benjamin André | - |  |  |  |  |
| Angel Gomes | - |  |  |  |  |
| Ivan Cavaleiro | - |  |  |  |  |
| Lucas Chevalier | - |  |  |  |  |
| Samuel Umtiti | - |  |  |  |  |
| Jonathan David | Big chances missed: 2 |  |  | 2 |  |

### Notes

I've changed the Regex pattern `(\d)` to `(\d+)` to ensure that if a `"Notes"` value has a numeric value that contains multiple digits, the `extract` method will retrieve all digits instead of just the first digit. In other words, if you have a value like `"Hit woodwork: 15"`, adding the `"+"` to ensures that the number `"15"` gets extracted instead of only the number `"1"`.

Comment: How can i thank you man.